# Is there a word for often re-read book?

Tags: single-word-requests

The book that a person might keep on their table, because they read it so often.

In Russian, there is an idiom with this meaning—["настольная книга"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0), which literally means "an on-table book".

Answer (score 3):

a [**well-thumbed**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/well-thumbed) book

> a well-thumbed book or magazine has been read many times

Answer (score 2):

In english we often call these books **"well-loved"**

> [well-loved books](http://www.twirlingpages.com/2016/02/08/well-loved-books/) "when the phrase “well-loved books” is used, we generally think of our tattered paperbacks or copies that are falling to SHAMBLES. i suppose the interpretation fits because it implies that you’ve read the book over and over and over again, and assumes your love for it is endless. BUT, half of my favorite “well-loved” books are in pristine condition. i would collapse if the pages creased or the spine broke or there was a strain on it. so that got me thinking… 
>   what makes a book “well-loved?”"

We also have "coffee table books" but they are often just for show - for decoration.  They are usually filled with pictures.

> [Coffee table books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_table_book)
>   "A coffee table book is an oversized, usually hard-covered book whose purpose is for display on a table intended for use in an area in which one entertains guests and from which it can serve to inspire conversation. Subject matter is predominantly non-fiction and pictorial (a photo-book). Pages consist mainly of photographs and illustrations, accompanied by captions and small blocks of text, as opposed to long prose. Since they are aimed at anyone who might pick up the book for a light read."

Answer (score 0):

Many times I've heard it expressed as 'pored over'. EBT

Comment: If a book is able to keep the reader's attention it is referred to as a 'page turner'. EBT

Comment: Sorry, Eddie B. True, and however many times you've heard "pored over" it doesn't equate to "re-read…" let alone to anything like "often…".

To "pore over" is broadly, to pay much attention to… how could that equate to "re-reading", let alone to "often re-reading"?