What's a word for a book that is read again and again like a bible?
I am looking for a word that describes a book that is read again and again like a bible. A book that is often gone to, not for reference but for reminders[1]. Like a book of maxims, manifesto, or aphorisms.
[1]: Some books append "Bible" to describe a book that is often used for reference or comprehensive teaching. E.g: Programmer's bible or Linux bible. I am not referring to those.
To clarify:  Reference is looking something [specific] up quickly for a task. The books I'm referring to are almost read in a ritual way without the purpose of finding specific information.

An adjective that describes such a book would be well-thumbed.  Are you looking for a description? Or a name?

I'm not sure there are many other books that are read over and over like the Bible. I don't think that books of maxims are used similarly. Bibles are somewhat unique in this regard.

What does 'not for reference but for reminders' mean?

I think your use of "bible" is confusing. Vademecum probably fits your description, but it's not clear.

Does anyone actually say 'vade mecum' outside of academia?

If the book is dipped into for comfort rather than for reference, it might be called a bedside book but I can't find a dictionary reference.

A perennial book...

@TimR A name like "Bible"? I have no specificity. It would be interesting to gather a list of words that apply to this.

@Barmar Bible is not the only holy book.Going to some books frequently might not be as common as going to songs frequently, but it is a thing.

@EdwinAshworth I clarified this in the footnote. Reference is looking something up quickly for a task. The books I'm referring to are almost read in a ritual way without the purpose of finding specific info.

@AvidSeeker I know, but I'm not sure what other books are frequently reread. Some people have a favorite book that they might reread, but this is about something that's commonly reread.

Very similar question to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450189/is-there-a-word-for-often-re-read-book?rq=1.  Alas, no really good answers to that one.

A favourite book? Metaphorically there are lots of terms like lodestar; and scripture etc. I don't know what specific term could apply to The Velveteen Rabbit and Mao's Little Red Book, so you probably want to be a little more precise about what kind of book and why. But my first thought was Andrew's vade mecum which is often used of a desktop reference but can have a much wider (metaphorical) usage.

The question lacks clarity.

In Christianity, works like this are usually called 'devotionals'.

Manifestos, maxims, aphorisms "devotionals"?

It it not clear why this question is closed as lacking 'details of clarity'. The concept of a book that is ' read again and again . . . in a ritual way without the purpose of finding specific information' is clear enough and intuitive enough that it is not crazy to think that there might be a word for it (which makes this unlike the many poorly thought-out single-word requests that appear on this site).

'Devotional", "encheridion", "guide", "guide-book", "primer", "guid âne", "manual" "hand-book" "missive".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Some of these are certainly used for reference, a guide-book almost entirely so.

Books that are read and reread over the years, books of pithy sayings, maxims, inspirational thoughts, manifestos, and such are known as "motivational" books.  Once upon a time, you could walk into a bookstore and ask, Where do you keep your motivational books?

It's always a risk to venture an answer on a poor question. There's always somebody who takes issue anonymously and without offering any reason whatsoever. One of the shitty things about an otherwise valuable forum.

This may be close to what the OP has in mind, but the word motivational is nowadays so often used in business-related and popular-psychology contexts that it sounds odd to characterise something like the Bible as motivational, even though it is literally true.

@Jsw29: Not sure why you're focusing so much on the bible when that book was presented only as an example of things read and re-read, for insight or inspiration (mind-reading OP's "reminders") and the body of the question  mentions "maxims, manifesto, or aphorisms".
